# Correct approach to make a ListBox Page Navigation using MVVM on Windows Phone

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-phone

I am building an app for Windows Phone, and in this app I have a list of Movies with Title, Plot and Picture.
I have this list bound to a ListBox with a custom DataTemplate for the items showing the data. I also created a second page to show the details of each movie.
My problem now is the navigation between these pages. I'm using MVVM to build the applications and most of the approaches I've found searching on internet is to use the OnSelectionChanged event in the code-behind, but it goes agains what I want, that is to use MVVM.

Other approach I've seen, which is the one I'm trying, is to bind the SelectedItem to a property in the ViewModel, but I can't make it change the property, it seems that I cannot select an item in the listbox. Also, I don't have the visual feedback when I press one of the items in my listbox, like the feedback we have in the settings menu of the phone for example.

The code I'm using in the listbox is:

```
<ListBox Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Movies}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMovieItem}" SelectionMode="Single" >
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,17">
                            <!--Replace rectangle with image-->
                            <Rectangle Height="50" Width="50" Fill="#FFE5001b" Margin="12,0,9,0"/>
                            <StackPanel Width="311">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" Foreground="#000" />
                                <!--<TextBlock Text="{Binding LineTwo}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>-->
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

Another approach I've seen is to use the INavigationService to achieve this, I found this article: http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/MVVM-in-real-life-Windows-Phone-applications-Part1
I read the parts one and two, but I couldn't understand this one works.

So, what I want to know is whether the approach I'm using is the correct to make a page navigation, or if there is a better way using MVVM to do this with visual feedback on the listbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is handling Event in the code behind against MVVM?  Handling events interaction is part of the UI. Of course you won't all you code logic there. But you are trying just to go to the next page. I do something like this :

```
    private void MainListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // If selected index is -1 (no selection) do nothing
        if (MainListBox.SelectedIndex == -1)
            return;

        // Navigate to the new page
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Views/detailsPage.xaml?selectedItem=" + MainListBox.SelectedIndex, UriKind.Relative));

        // Reset selected index to -1 (no selection)
        MainListBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }
```

Comment: I want to open other page in my software, Isn't there another way of doint it, with the logic in the ViewModel?

Comment: I've tried what you said, showing a MessageBox for the item I selected, there is another problem now, I don't have visual feedback when I click one item.

Comment: Well ViewModel should not know anything about the view. Here you are just trying to move from one view to another. How are you trying to show a messageBox?

Comment: I managed to make it work even with visual feedback, I followed this article [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff941108).
The only thing now is to pass data to the other page, how can I do this? Do I have to pass it as a parameter in the uri like in web-pages?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I haven't noticed that you put the solution to pass data between the pages in the code! Perfect! Thank you very much!